# Are there any mathematics based jobs by Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, math-se, internships

I would really like to develop my life towards mathematics (more specifically number theory). When talking to my current precalculus teacher, she recommended an internship. After some looking, however, I could not find any! Is there a chance that a Mathematics internship could be created through this site for high school students? Note, this internship does not have to do with specifically number theory, but more about a general mathematics internship. I am not sure what to tag this, so please edit before downvoting :)

EDIT: Ok, I guess interships are not an option, but would it be possible to have a math job here? I don't know how to program, by the way.

Comment: @Doorknob This is specifically to mathematics

Comment: The same answer applies.

Comment: @Doorknob True, but then again, that was a year ago